# form submit error stating .then is not an error

Tags: javascript

When I submit the form on my client-side I am getting the error

```
(index):83 Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.Submit
```

which is pointing to the following line of code:

```
.then((res) => res.json())
```

which is within this code block:

```
function Submit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let body = document.getElementById('search').nodeValue;

      fetch ("/:url + theURL"), {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-type': 'applcation.json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({search:search})
    }
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid this issue?

Comment: little tip: count the parentheses and braces, the number of openings must equal the number of closures. and use a clean indent ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error. You should move the closing parentheses to after all parameters of the fetch function.

```
fetch ("/:url + theURL", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-type': 'applcation.json'
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({search:search})
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data))
```